# How to fix StaleElementReferenceException in selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

**Problem:**
Iam getting this error : selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

**My Aim:**
It is to scrape whatsapp web elements for my web scraping project, but whatsapp has limit of 15 elements to view at a time on a viewport,if you scroll down you will get new 15 elements for new conversations tab, **so i just need my code to actually scrape all of the elements by scrolling down slowly, not directly scrolling down to the page as it would not get me my all conversations(limit is 15 elements at a time) I have tried other solutions, don't work**

**My code in which i struggle to achieve my aim but fail to do so and also try to bypass the error:**

```
conversations = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_2wP_Y']")         # to get conversations tab
    while True:
        for conversation in conversations:
            wait_for_element = 20
            self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", conversation)
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, wait_for_element).until(
                    expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, '_2wP_Y'))
            )
```

Thanks in advance, Please include code as it will help me better understand